# como enviar archivo XML por correo sin almacenarlo en el servidor con Laravel 9?

Tags: php, xml, laravel-9

Quisiera enviar por correo un archivo XML construido con la libreria DOMDocument, pero este archivo no se debe guardar en el servidor ya que actualmente lo estoy almacenando.

```
$DOMDocumentXML = new DOMDocument();
$DOMDocumentXML->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$DOMDocumentXML->formatOutput = true;
$DOMDocumentXML->loadXML(view("xml.invoice", $data));
$DOMDocumentXML->save('archivo.xml');
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Usa el método [`saveXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.savexml.php).

Comment: @Sal Gracias me sirvió mucho, amigo ahora quisiera comprimir en ZIP este archivo, es posible hacer eso o necesariamente para comprimir el archivo debo guardarlo en el disco ?

Comment: Es posible, hay librerías y un par de trucos para eso. Aunque es cuestionable si vale la pena el ahorro en ancho de banda con el costo de usabilidad para el usuario. Amerita otra pregunta.